# stepper motor driver amp

Tags: transistors, pcb-design, design, stepper-motor

I want to add a few amps to the output of a stepper motor driver (bipolar 4 wire) with out modifying the interns of the driver.
**MY QUESTION IS BEFORE I START I WANT TO ASK IF THERE IS A PROBLEM WITH MY IDEA BELOW AND OR MY SCHEMATIC.** 
My idea is pull ground +24 and the 4 wires that go to the motor and make them switch some transistors like so. Again I want to know if there is a problem here with component values and what not. I only ask because I tend to dew stupid stuff and i do not want to blow this up.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6PUuQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
PS: sorry for caps I keep getting marked down for not having a clear question.

Comment: Your NPNs are backwards, and your part placement [looks strange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge).

Comment: You are showing two H bridges but the schematic is very hard to read the way the devices are arranged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rearranged version of your schematic looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLpGLW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problems have already been mentioned by jippie, and rearranging the schematic shows that the lower four transistors (Q8,Q9,Q6,Q11) are inverted (collector<->emitter).
Also note that even if the level of the bridge supply was the same as the control level you would need to use one resistor for each base because a common one would make both upper/lower transistors conduct simultaneously.

One solution you can use to control the bridge from two logic level control signals is shown in [A simple H-Bridge design](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2009/03/a-simple-h-bridge-design/)

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "(Q8,Q9,Q6,Q11) are inverted (collector<->emitter)." I superpose it is a H bridge on each coil

Comment: @RexFenderBaird So your intension was in each vertical couple to have the upper transistor used in common emitter configuration (output from collector) and the lower transistor used in common collector configuration (output from the emitter)? And what about the current that flows from +24 to the emitter of the PNP, to the base of the PNP, to the base of NPN and to the ground ?

Answer (score 0):

The circuit won't work because Q7, 5, 3 and 6 are always active unless you have 24V microcontroller outputs. On top of that Q8, 9, 10 and 11 will not be driven reliably, because the emitter voltage varies with current through the stepper's windings.

1. Convert the 0/5V microcontroller output to 0/24V logic, able to source sufficient current to drive the power transistors.
2. Use the 24V-logic to control a power stage.
3. It is really tricky to get a power driver working with emitter (or source when using MOSFETs) at the power rail, tie the collectors to the rail use the power transistors as emitter follower (common collector).

Comment: the controller is a gshield that alone powers the motor at 24V I am trying to step up the current is all so basically i'm working with 24V logic and I thought I would need a voltage divider from the controller to the transistors because that run a 5v max bace?